# Showing a progress bar while file is being copied from bundle to documents path

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, nsfilemanager

I am making an application where at the time of log in I am **coping** some file from **my main bundle** to the **applications document's directory**. It takes around 3-4 mins. During this period I am showing an activity indicator to the user.

However I would like to show a **progress bar** so that the user is aware of the percentage of copy being done. Has anybody come across such scenario?

Any suggestion, would be of great help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `YLProgressBar` project by Yannick Loriot is really easy to implement and does the essentials of what you are trying to achieve.

You can find the Open Source (MIT - licenced) project [here](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/ylprogressbar).

Hope it helps!

PS. [Here](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=progress) is other Open Source progress views if the `YLProgressBar` isn't to your liking.